# How set image style in theme. android?

Tags: android, themes

I am making a multi-theme application, and I want set tint attribute to all images in depends current theme.

Like this

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Default" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#EA7819</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#CF6415</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#3498DB</item>

        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Theme.AppCompat</item>
    </style>
```

I can set toolbar style in theme, can I do something similar with imageView?

Comment: Sorry, of course, it is `tint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the tint color in each of your `ImageView` as below:

```
// define your attr
<resources>
   <attr name="image_tint_color" format="reference"/>
</resources>
// create multiple themes: YourTheme1, YourTHeme2...
<style name="YourTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="image_tint_color">yourColor</item>
</style>
// After setting theme in activity:
setTheme(R.style.yourTheme1)
// Then you can use the color everywhere:
android:tint="?attr/image_tint_color"
```

You can take a look at the [Detail Guide Here](https://medium.com/@vinitagrawal91/android-colors-and-multiple-themes-fdfca3f75a15)

Comment: wow, really thanks!
I don't know, that may define a custom attribute